Cannot crop correctly with openCV in Python
I want to crop the identity card off of this scan

Mind, that there is a lot of white space under the id (until here)
First, I preprocess the image:
def preprocess_before_crop_2(scan_path, output_dir):
    # Read the image
    original_image = cv2.imread(scan_path)
    # Grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Histogram Equalization on grayscale image
    equalized = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
    # Initial Denoising
    denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(equalized, None, h=20, templateWindowSize=7, searchWindowSize=21)
    # Sharpening kernel
    kernel = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]])
    sharpened = cv2.filter2D(denoised, -1, kernel)
    # Bilateral filter
    bilateral_filtered = cv2.bilateralFilter(sharpened, d=9, sigmaColor=75, sigmaSpace=75)
    # Increase Contrast
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    contrast = clahe.apply(bilateral_filtered)
    # Apply slight Gaussian blur before binarization for anti-aliasing
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(contrast, (3, 3), 0)
    # Binary conversion with Otsu's thresholding
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(blurred, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    # Adaptive thresholding
    adaptive_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
    return adaptive_thresh

then I use it to crop the image:
def crop_document(scan_path, output_dir):
    original_image = cv2.imread(scan_path)
    # preprocess image
    preprocessed_image = preprocess_before_crop(scan_path, output_dir)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(preprocessed_image,cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    # Find object with the biggest bounding box
    mx = (0,0,0,0)      # biggest bounding box so far
    mx_area = 0
    areas = []
    for cont in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
        area = w*h
        ratio = float(w) / float(h)
        areas.append((area,ratio))
        if area > mx_area and ratio > 1:
            mx = x,y,w,h
            mx_area = area

    x,y,w,h = mx

    # Crop and save
    cropped_image=original_image[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    return cropped_image

However, the resulting cropped image looks like this: (I added a red rectangle of what I would like to crop instead)

I tried to remove/change some steps in the preprocessing steps, but to no avail.
Edit:
This was the image I originally uploaded, sorry if anyone was confused.


so there's a black border around parts of the entire scan. either handle that, or handle passport images specifically.

Did you really change the input image? What will happen after someone amends their answer and you encounter another example that is not covered by the extended answer? Will you change the image again ad nauseam? Not cool, OP, that's a huge waste of everybody's time.

@stateMachine I checked the history and compared. OP merely replaced the content of the ID card. all the surrounding debris and noise remains identical. none of these changes should affect anyone's solution. r1 and r3 are identical upto less severe obfuscation of personally identifiable data.

not a solution, just thoughts: this is a standard application for scanners and photocopiers. use google scholar, browse patents. photocopiers have been around for several decades. even a 20 year old patent will show good results. problems: (1) black borders (2) small debris. black borders can be cropped off blindly (manual adjustment, device constant), or you can try to detect them. small debris can be removed with various thresholding and morphology operations. what remains is a mask for the foreground/object, which is hopefully not as white as the bed cover. that's all.

@stateMachine you are absolutely right, I didn't think of that. I added the image I used initially in the question at the bottom.

@ChristophRackwitz well, the new image appears to be darker which throws off the adaptive thresholding, opening the borders of the ID. I have proposed a few approaches (changing the thresholding method or using Canny Edge Detection instead). However, I don't see much effort from OP to understand the limitations of their own code. Otherwise, they would have quickly noticed that both the equalize method and adaptive thresholding method affect the contours of interest (which is basically the beauty of image analysis). Therefore, I will not further elaborate on my answer.

hold on. you're saying the picture with the better contrasting (darker, on white) card does worse with your answer? then your answer strikes me as fragile and needs work. -- questions on SO often present code that should summarily go into the trash bucket. valiant attempts, fair proof of work, but better to start from scratch than try to make it work. you should go for the inferred goal, starting from the data.

The problem is that your object of interest is connected to that top left black corner.
This already occurs at the cv2.equalizeHist() step:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(equalized)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()


Simply ignoring that step and taking the SECOND largest contour will do the job:
denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, None, h=20, templateWindowSize=7, searchWindowSize=21)

# ...

preprocessed_image = adaptive_thresh

#sort by area
contours = cv2.findContours(preprocessed_image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

#select 2nd largest contour
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[1])

cropped_image=original_image[y:y+h,x:x+w]

#display cropped image
plt.imshow(cropped_image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

#display the respective contour
cv2.drawContours(original_image, [contours[1]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 20)
plt.imshow(original_image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

The cropped image:

The contours of interest:

EDIT:
Instead of choosing the second largest contour you could further specify the object of interest by computing shape-related metrics, e.g.
area = list()
perimeter = list()
circularity = list()
aspectRatio = list()
cx = list() #centroid cooords
cy = list() #centroid coords
xydist = list() #distance of contour centroid to image center

for c in contours:
    area.append(cv2.contourArea(c))
    perimeter.append(cv2.arcLength(c, closed = True))
    if int(cv2.arcLength(c, closed = True)) == 0: #avoid division by '0'
       circularity.append(0) #dummy value
    else: 
       circularity.append((4*math.pi*cv2.contourArea(c))/ cv2.arcLength(c, closed = True)**2)
    
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    aspectRatio.append(float(w)/h)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
  
    if int(M['m00']) == 0: #avoid division by '0'
        cx.append(0) #dummy value
        cy.append(0) #dummy value
        xydist.append(0) #dummy value
    else: 
        cx.append(int(M['m10']/M['m00']))
        cy.append(int(M['m01']/M['m00']))
        xydist.append(abs(int(M['m01']/M['m00']) - original_image.shape[0]/2) + abs(int(M['m01']/M['m00']) - original_image.shape[1]/2))

Now, for example, if the area of an object is much larger than expected, it can be simply removed by applying a threshold.

Thanks, I should have clarified, that I also have to crop other IDs, where this problem does not occur. So, I would only have to take the second contour in this example. Can you think of another, more general solution?

If the ID is always similar in size (area) and no other similarly sized objects can be expected then you can you simply check whether the contour area of the largest object is plausible: cv2.contourArea(contours[0]) > threshold

Thanks, I think this looks promising. However, can you elaborate your edit or even provide a more complete example?

@Selphiron I have added a few examples. Without knowing how much your images actually differ there's not much more I can do. I'll leave the rest to you.

Thanks again, I like your idea with the aspect ratio. However, cv2.findcontours cannot find the correct contours for my image (see updated question). Do you have a solution for that? Thanks for your efforts so far!

@Selphiron I'm sorry but I don't get the impression that you actually understand the code you are working with. You could simply look at the result of each processing step and would have easily noticed that the adaptive thresholding does not work for the new image (the new image you uploaded is 'darker'). Perhaps try a Canny Edge Detector followed by dilation or other morphological operations to detect the borders of the ID more reliably.

Alternatively, changing the adaptive threshold method to cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C might already suffice.


Cannot crop correctly with openCV2

I would recommend to use mouse events.

Just draw rectangle.
Press s to save it

Snippet:
import cv2 as cv

refPt = []
cropping = False

def click_crop(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global refPt, cropping, num
    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        refPt = [(x, y)]
        cropping = True

    if event == cv.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        num += 1
        refPt.append((x, y))
        cropping = False        
        cv.rectangle(img, refPt[0], refPt[1], (0, 255, 0), 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num = 0

    windowName = 'Click and Crop'
    img = cv.imread('l.png', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
    clone = img.copy()
    cv.namedWindow(windowName)

    cv.setMouseCallback(windowName, click_crop)

    num = 0
    if len(refPt) == 2:
        num += 1

    while True:
        cv.imshow(windowName, img)
        key = cv.waitKey(1)
        if key == ord("r"): 
            img = clone.copy()
        elif key == ord("s"):   
            roi = clone[refPt[0][1]:refPt[1][1], refPt[0][0]:refPt[1][0]]
            cv.imwrite('roi{}.jpg'.format(num), roi)            
        elif key == ord("c"):  
            break    
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

Screenshot:

Output:


Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't think that it is viable though, since I have thousands of documents and I need to automate the process.
